# Can't map array data in react js to child component

Tags: reactjs

I am using react and react-dom version "^16.12.0";

I would like to use the material ui multi selectbox with chips inside of my react js project. Therefore I need to map my array into the list as an `<MenuItem>`. I am getting the
`Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {value, label}).If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.` 
I have already tried the  `Object.keys(races).map`  and Object.entries(races).map ``` and I also tried to put this into a const inside of render, but I'm always getting the same error...

Here's the snippet which isn't working (inside of a calss component):

```
              <Grid item xs={6}>
                <Select
                  name="dogName"
                  multiple
                  id="select"
                  value={this.state.dogName}
                  onChange={this.handleChangeMultiple.bind(this)}
                  input={<TextField />}
                  renderValue={(selected) => (
                    <div style={{display: 'flex',flexWrap: 'wrap',}}>
                      {selected.map((value) => (
                        <Chip key={value} label={value} style={{margin: 2,}} />
                      ))}
                    </div>
                  )}
                  >
                  {races.map((name) => (
                    <MenuItem key={name.value} value={name.label} >
                      {name}
                    </MenuItem>
                  ))}
                </Select>
              </Grid>
```

And here is the array (in it's own '.js' file, imported as `import {races} from './helper/dograces.js';`):

```
export const races = [
    {value: 'unknown', label: 'unknown'},
    {value: 'B1', label: 'Bulldog'},
    {value: 'P1', label: 'Pitbull'},
...
]
```

Please help .. I really don't understand where the problem is..!

Best regards!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Child component do not accept an object type. I guest you want to show label in items menu. Your code should be:

```
{races.map((name) => (
                <MenuItem key={name.value} value={name.label} >
                  {name.label}
                </MenuItem>
              ))}
```

Comment: Yes, this is even more accurate  but @norbitrial unfortunately I don't know how to mark answers as "final"..

Comment: You can check here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer :))))

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers. I believe you can do that!

Answer (score 1):

The main problem is not with the `.map()` part itself or with `<MenuItem />` but the children.

Try as the following instead:

```
{races.map((name) => (
  <MenuItem key={name.value} value={name.label}>
     {name.value}
  </MenuItem>
))}
```

I've changed from `{name}` to `{name.value}` because `name` is an object which is **not a valid React child** as the error message states. Instead using `name.value` will be a valid one as it's a **string**.

Comment: Thanks a lot! 
A bit embarrassing that I wasn't aware of this ><
Now other errors appear but I think I can handle them :)
Have a nice evening!

Comment: @ninja Happy to help! :) If the solution worked, please consider accepting as the answer for your question, thank you!